# How to change the size of QSharedMemory

Tags: c++, qt, ipc, shared-memory

I want to create a shared memory segment for IPC between processes, but the variables that I want to put in that shared segment is changing dynamically and increasing all the time, the examples I saw are creating it with fixed size, and I looked in the class reference of QSharedMemory and found no function for resizing.

what to do but without suggesting to create new shared segments cause I want one segment with one key for availability at run time to other processes.

Answer (score 2):

You can not, both applications should agree on a size and create memory for it at the beginning.

If you really want re-size it, you have to close the previous memory and create a new memory again.

In this case both applicatios must know what's going on.

Comment: so we can not use dynamic sized variables like QList or QMap in shared memory? @M M.

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass a `QList` or `QMap` via shared memory by their pointers?!

Comment: I mean that I want a QList to be created in shared memory to be accessible to other processes, I want them to read/update it @M M.

Comment: So, make your shared memory big enough. I think it's the only solution

Comment: theoriticaly, I can do this, but at run time you can't manage this , I mean what if the list got larger than the shared segment? and I can't make the segment quiet large cause I have limited resources, and what actually made me think in shared memory as IPC is to reduce memory consuming via copying these data in any other IPC. @M M.

Comment: Is there no other approach (using a Qt class or not) to achieve this? Note that you don't have to share the QMap or QList pointer itself, one can share the serialised representation (created via a QDataStream(QByteArray&) object).